# How to install osqa on linux based web hosting

Tags: linux, osqa

How to install osqa on linux based web hosting, is there any easiest way to install osqa on a linux based shared hosting account ?

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way I found is to deploy to the EC2 Cloud using [Turnkey Linux OSQA Virtual Appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/osqa). or you could deploy on in internal network using the iso to install it.